# r group maddison data by continent and year

Tags: r, ggplot2

I downloaded the maddison data for gdp over time and space. I want a simple graph that summarises gdp per continent from year 1 - 2003 (that´s the end of the data).

I wrote

```
install.packages("maddison")
library(maddison)
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

str(maddison)

maddi <- maddison

library(lubridate)

maddi$year <- as.character(maddi$year)
maddi$year2 <- substr(maddi$year, start = 1, stop = 4)
maddi$year2 <- as.numeric(maddi$year2)

table(maddi$continent)
table(maddi$region)


maddi2 <- maddi[ which(maddi$continent == 'Asia'| maddi$continent == 'Europe'| maddi$continent == 'Africa'), ]
maddi3 <- maddi2 [!(maddi2$region == "Southern Europe" | maddi2$region == "Northern Europe"), ]

library('stringr')

maddi3$continent <- ifelse(maddi3$continent == "Europe" & maddi3$region == "Eastern Europe", maddi3$continent == "Eastern Europe", maddi3$continent) 
maddi3$continent <- str_replace_all(maddi3$continent, 'FALSE', 'Eastern Europe')
maddi3$continent <- str_replace_all(maddi3$continent, 'Europe', 'Western Europe')

table(maddi3$continent)

maddi4 <- maddi3 [!(maddi3$country == "Japan"), ]

library(dplyr)

maddi4 %>% 
  group_by(continent) %>% 
  ggplot(maddi4, aes(x=year2, y=gdp_pc, color=continent)) +
  geom_line(size=1) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Total GDP ($ trillions)") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12)
```

the final graph though is not what I want of course. how can I obtain the easy graph i am able to create with excel? 
[image]

I would also be happy for some hints on write better and more elegant code for this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will give you the right plot ;)

```
maddi4 %>% 
  group_by(continent, year2) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(gdp_pc, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  drop_na() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year2, y=mean, color=continent)) +
  geom_line(size=1) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Total GDP ($ trillions)") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12)
```

[image]

Comment: Breaks in OPs plot have different scaling

Comment: it does! ok, so the group_by and the summarising were the main issues. I understand. Thanks mate!